# Profile - Organisation Details but add employee/voluntter

Tags: profile

I am creating a profile for Organisations to complete on our website and it seems straighforward. Until it gets to finding how to add employees/volunteers as part of the profile.

How do I get an organisation to enter these details?

Thanks

Comment: This is good question. There are several approaches. Can you provide the CMS you are using? Depending on which CMS the approaches will vary.

Comment: Sorry. Wordpress

Answer (score 3):

For WordPress you will need to use Caldera Forms to achieve what you are looking to do. Here is a link to the documentation:

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/website-integration/integrating-with-wordpress/#caldera-forms-civicrm

Here is a link to the Caldera Forms CiviCRM integration on Git Hub:

https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm

Hope this helps